# Create new table and naming it with user input from QLineEdit

Tags: c++, mysql, qt5

Im making a MYSQL database using QT5 on my raspberry pi. Already made all app and localhost and everything ok so far. My question is on how to create a new table  named by user from a qlineEdit on the UI, when pressing a button?

Here the code I have for the button slot:

```cpp
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QSqlQuery query;
    query.prepare( "CREATE TABLE `QT`.`tlb` ( `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `desde` 
    VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL , `hasta` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL , `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , 
    `color` TEXT NOT NULL , `circuits_qty` INT(65) NOT NULL , `customer` TEXT NULL , 
    `program` TEXT NULL , `family` TEXT NULL , `location` VARCHAR(40) NULL , `con1` 
    LONGBLOB NULL , `con2` LONGBLOB NULL , `con3` LONGBLOB NULL , `con4` LONGBLOB NULL , 
    `con5` LONGBLOB NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB");
    
    QString name;
    name = ui->lineEdit->text();
    query.bindValue(":'tlb', 'name'");
    // query.prepare("ALTER TABLE 'tlb' RENAME TO name;)
    query.exec();
}
```

As you can see, code works when just giving a name by me. But when trying to make the user give the name to the table, nothing happens. I made a QString to get the name from the qlineEdit store the name then, tried to bind it, but did not work, then tried an alter table but still nothing happened. Any help is more than welcome. Commented out the alter table btw just to go back and forward trying different ways to get this works.

Answer (score 0):

Since **tlb** is the placeholder for the table and name is the qstring given by the user, your call should look like:

```
query.bindValue(":'tlb'", name);
```